# jQuery if input value is default, prevent default on submit

Tags: jquery, html, input, default-value

I have a form, I want to disable the submit function if the input's value is default.

```
<input id="company" name="companyname" value="company">
<input type="submit" class="button">
```

I tried this jquery:

```
$(".button").click(function(e){
    if($("#company").attr('value', 'defaultValue'))
       {
           alert("Please fill out the contact form."); 
           e.preventDefault();
       }
   });
```

But it doesn't work as expected, it fires and brings up the alert as intended but also changes the value of the input to "defaultValue."

I am stumped :) What am I doing wrong?

[You can see it in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/69HjD/).

Comment: Sorry, what are you trying to achieve here? Do you want to prevent the post if the value in the textbox hasn't changed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With

```
if ($("#company").attr('value', 'defaultValue'))
```

You're setting the `value` to `defaultValue`. Do this instead:

```
if ($("#company").attr('value') == 'defaultValue'))
```

**Thanks Ryan**: it's probably better to use `.val()` instead of `.attr('value')` in case the current value has changed since the value specified in the HTML attribute, and jQuery doesn't handle that specially.

Do this:

```
if ($("#company").val() == 'defaultValue'))
```

Comment: @Delan; http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/69HjD/1/ I inserted your suggested code, now it doesn't display the alert. @Ryan: I did that also and it just changed the value as before.

Comment: Sorry, there's a minor syntax error in my answer. Try again now.

Comment: You've made an error copying my answer. You wrote `if ($("#company").val('defaultValue')`, but my answer is `if ($("#company").val() == 'defaultValue'))`.

Comment: Corrected but still no dice. :/ jsLint returned: `Problem at line 2 character 47: Expected '{' and instead saw ')'.
if ($("#company").val() == 'defaultValue'))`

Comment: You copied my answer wrong again. Remove the last closing parentheses.

Comment: I copied it as it is, I even removed the last parenthesis, in your example the alert isn't showing either.. I like this solution better than the others, so I hope we can get it working :) http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/8nW2j/1/

Comment: Your latest link works now. I think you may have misunderstood. `company` is not `defaultValue`, so it passes through. If you write `defaultValue` in the text box, the alert will show and the form will not submit.

Comment: Ooohhh I see, I have misunderstood! I thought defaultValue found the value of the HTML input and used that.. I can work with this now, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

If the default value is simply there as a prompt to change the value, if possible consider using the new HTML5 [`placeholder`](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#placeholder) attribute. You can even [use jQuery to help browsers that don't support it yet](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/Placeholder-jQuery-Plugin). This way you don't need to bother checking if it is a default value.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/pKBMu/

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use this right now. Bosses and such. But thanks for the tip :)

Comment: That's a shame, it's quite a beautiful thing.

Answer (score 1):

Right I know this has been answered but I had some time so I wrote up a quick framework that would let you track changes easily. Basically what this will do is to monitor all input elements that you have on the form and will visually track their changes by giving them a special class when the value is changed. Thus at a glance the user can see what they have changed. Further this small framework would also stop you from posting the form back if none of the input elements have changed. You can expand this framework to include more elements by changing the selector!

```
.changedValue
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #0c5403 !important;
    background: #e1fedd !important;
}

<input id="company" name="companyname" value="company"/>
<input type="submit" class="button"/>

$('input').live('focusin', function() {
    var tx = this,
        jqt = $(tx);

    //store the original value if we don't already have it
    if (typeof(tx.defaultValue) == 'undefined') {
        tx.defaultValue = tx.value;
    }

})
//control change
.live('focusout', function() {
    var t = this,
        jqThis = $(t);
    jqThis[t.defaultValue != t.value ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('changedValue');


});


$(".button").click(function(e) {
    if ($("input.changedValue").length == 0) {
        alert("Please fill out the contact form.");
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this with .val():

http://jsfiddle.net/69HjD/2/

You're probably going to want to extend this further so perhaps look at a validation plugin for jQuery?